# Generate smaller post thumbnail for archives

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a blog style page where every post has a post thumbnail. Since I have 5-10 posts on my front page it pulls down my page ranking, because the post thumbnails are vastly bigger on the post page than on the front page. With the exception of one image, they're all scaled down 60-70% in CSS.

Know of any guides or tips to have WordPress copy and scale down the now new version of the image, so I can use that on the front page, while I'll still have the full size one on the post pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think from your question you might want to look at adding a new thumbnail image size into your functions.php

```
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

You'll then need to regenerate the post thumbnails, as you've added a new image size, there is a plugin called "Regenerate Thumbnails"

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Then you'll need to set the front-page.php to use this new thumbnail image size when it constructs the blog index - themes do this in various ways, generally you'll need to look at

```
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```